# What are the components of an Angular/Node/ng application? What does each do and how are they related?

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I'm having version issues installing npm/node/angular/ng.  What are the different components of an Angular/Node/ng application and how are they related?  Are there bundled packages that include everything you need to start developing in a single download?  The current project I'm on is managing all of this through npm and is going through the common growing pains of changing versions and changing components and changing dependencies. The [npm documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/) is good for npm basics but is there documentation that describes best (or common, or recommended) practices for installing everything needed for Angular/node/ng applications (@angular-devkit, @angular-cdk, @schematics/angular, ng, etc.).

Comment: The... *Angular* documentation? https://angular.io/docs

Comment: This was helpful: https://angular.io/guide/npm-packages but I'm not seeing where I can find a list of versions.  I've been told the project is on 6.2.2 but when I run npm install -g angular-cli@6.2.2 I get a version not found error.  Is there a way I can list the available versions?

Comment: Available versions of `angular-cli`? See http://npmjs.com/package/angular-cli, but that's not the package you actually want... And 6.2.2 isn't even the newest of the 6.x line, I'd recommend starting with something substantially more recent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The starting point is as follows visiting https://cli.angular.io/ which shows you how to start an Angular app from scratch using Angular CLI. 
Now let's say you create a temp folder and do the following as described in above link:

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
ng new my-dream-app
cd my-dream-app
ng serve
```

Go to this folder and check the package.json file in the root of that project against yours. That should surely give you the idea of which packages you have.

As the next step run the following command

```
npm-check -u
```

and as the final tip: every now and then delete the contents of node_modules (make sure you have everything backed up) and do a

```
npm install
```

Then run

```
ng build --prod
```

This way around you can always be sure if you clone your app on some other machine, you can install all the dependencies and resume work and also your project builds with no issue.

Comment: I think one of the things that I'm struggling with is what should be a global install and what should be local to the project for npm installs and what is getting committed to our version management system (git).  What files are written to by "ng build --prod"?  "/node_modules" is in our .gitignore.  Is there a way to save the npm configuration for the project without saving "/node_modules" (I assume node_modules is the compiled code -- it's pretty big, ~500Mb)?

Comment: /node_modules folder should not be any source of your worry because [ considering you have good internet connection ], you can always manually empty that folder and do a simple "npm install". I think you already know that the contents of /node_modules never gets checked-in into the source control. The only thing you check-in is package.json. Now if you upgrade some packages and check-in, the other developer who gets the latest version can simply empty his /node_modules folder and do a "npm install" again.My /node_modules folder is 720MB and I could always empty it and reinstall them as I wish.